# jinja ansible flat array template loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to loop over a simple list of strings & insert each of them into an ansible jinja template, but when looping over the variable in the template file, I get

AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'item' is undefined

```
-- vars.yml
services:
  - "service 1"
  - "service 2"

-- main.yml
  win_template:
    with_items: "{{ services }}"

-- jinja template
    (% for item in services %)
    {{ item }}
    (% endfor %)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this turned out to be really simple in the end, no array loops, purely

```
{{ services|join("\n") }}
```

in the template file.